# Check if method's parameter was set by user

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters, optional-parameters

Is there a way to check if the parameter of the method was set by the default value set in the method itself or by the user who called the method?

Here's what I want to do in my method, for example

```
def json_prop(key, value = nil)
    json_data = {} if json_data.nil?
    return json_data[key] if value.set_by_user? # i.e. User did not set value to nil himself
    json_data[key] = value # Set to the value inserted by the user when calling the method
end
```

Comment: What behaviour do you expect if `nil` is passed explicitly? For example if someone calls `json_prop("some_key", nil)`, do you consider this as value set by the user?

Comment: Exactly.
If I can know if the user set the 2nd value or not, I can determine whether he requested to set a property (i.e. setter) or to get a property's value (i.e. getter).

That is my desire to do in the first place.
Thou I'm not sure such feature exist in any programming language.

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard trick to do this, and it relies on two features of the Ruby programming language:

1. The default argument value for an optional parameter is a Ruby expression and thus can contain any arbitrary Ruby code and
2. Local variables defined in the default argument value expression are in scope in the method's body.

Therefore, all we need to do is set a variable in the default argument value expression, and we know: if the variable is set, the default argument value expression was evaluated and thus no argument value was passed:

```ruby
def json_prop(key, value = (no_value_set_by_user = true; nil))
  json_data = {} if json_data.nil?
  return json_data[key] if no_value_set_by_user
  json_data[key] = value
end
```

or

```ruby
def json_prop(key, value = (
  no_value_set_by_user = true
  nil
))
  json_data = {} if json_data.nil?
  return json_data[key] if no_value_set_by_user
  json_data[key] = value
end
```

Comment: This is absolutely incredible, well done